# Using a variable with fwrite and next line

Tags: matlab, line-breaks

So i have written a loop that reads a series of .txt files line by line and consolidates them all into a new .txt file. The problem is that it just globs them all in there and I cannot figure out how to have it go to the next line after writting one.

```
 steve = fopen('JuneWeather.txt','at');
       for i =152:181
        filename= sprintf('weather_data_2019_%d.txt', i);
        fid1=fopen(sprintf('%s%d',path,filename));  %.... open the file, MATLAB assigns an ID
        count=-1;              %     line counter
        while ~feof(fid1)      %     test for end of file (EOF)
            line=fgetl(fid1);  %     get the next line
            %disp(line);        %     show the line
            fwrite(steve, line);
            fwrite(steve, '\n');
            count=count+1;
            % if count>100; break; end;  %  only for debugging
            if count==0; continue; end   %  skip the header line 
            %  header line in the file:
            %Datetime,RecNbr,WS_mph_Avg,PAR_Den_Avg,WS_mph_S_WVT,WindDir_SD1_WVT,AirTF_Avg,Rain_in_Tot,RH,WindDir_D1_WVT
            %  return;  %... stops script right here
        end
        fclose(fid1);
        end
    fclose(steve)
```

The best result I have gotten is a \n between each line, no line breaks.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fwrite interprets your \n as two characters and not the newline character you are looking for.

If you have matlab >2016b you can just use newline instead:

```
fwrite(steve,newline);
```

If you don't, you need to know which operating system you are on:
Windows:

```
fwrite(steve,sprintf('\r\n'));
```

Unix:

```
fwrite(steve,sprintf('\n'));
```

In addition, you can have a look at the fprintf function. This one interprets escape sequences like \n and so on.

Also, please check the line:

```
fid1=fopen(sprintf('%s%d',path,filename));
```

I suspect it should read:

```
fid1=fopen(sprintf('%s%s',path,filename));
```

However, I would advise to use the function

```
fid1=fopen(fullfile(path, filename));
```

which takes care of stuff like \ / for unix/windows systems.

Edit: Just in case you want to use the fprintf function instead of fwrite: 
remove the fwrite lines and replace with.

```
fprintf(steve, '%s\n',line);
```

(The %s is important, otherwise fprintf might interpret any \ characters as escape sequence.)

Answer (score 0):

### The problems:

There are several things wrong or at least confusing about your code:

Firstly, you open the output file in `'text'` mode (indicated by the `t` in your file opening statement `steve=fopen('JuneWeather.txt','at');`). This is good as you are dealing with text files but then you go on to use `fwrite`, which is a low level function specialised for writing *binary* data.

I'll give you below a solution with [`fprintf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) as I really recommend to use the proper function for the job, specially when you are unsure of what you are doing.

Also, you missed the fact that the definition of [`fgetl`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) is : *Read line from file, **removing newline characters***.
So of course you'll have to place a newline character at the end of each line since every time you read one line the original newline character is dumped.

Regarding the newline character to chose from, you could use an automatic method like:

```
if ispc
    strNewline = '\r\n' ;
else
    strNewline = '\n' ;
end
```

But in your case that's not even necessary. Since you opened your output file in *text* mode, the documentation tells you:

> To open files in text mode, attach the letter 't' to the permission
>   argument, such as 'rt' or 'wt+'.
>
> On Windows® systems, in text mode:
>
> ```
> - Read operations that encounter a carriage return followed by a newline character ('\r\n') remove the carriage return from the input.
> - Write operations insert a carriage return before any newline character in the output.
> ```

The last line is your clue, MATLAB will automatically manage the carriage return (the `\r` character), so you not need to bother with it. Just use only `\n` when you need it.

(*note that on a PC computer, if you hadn't opened the file in text mode you would have to insert the carriage return yourself if you wanted it*).

---

### The solution(s):

For the purpose of the example, I created 2 text files `test_1.txt` and `test_2.txt` which only contains a header and a few lines of coma separated values each. 
The code that works and is the closest to your implementation is as follow (I removed the debugging lines about `count` and the comments, feel free to reinsert it where desired):

```
fileOut = 'testout.txt' ;
steve = fopen(fileOut,'at');
for i =1:2
    fid1=fopen(sprintf('test_%d.txt', i));
    while ~feof(fid1)
        % This reads the line, but REMOVE the newline character at the end
        line=fgetl(fid1);
        % so we write the line and ADD the newline character at the end
        fprintf(steve, [line '\n']);
    end
    fclose(fid1);
end
fclose(steve) ;
```

**Alternatively:**

Since you are working with text file and seem to be simply *merging* them without actually doing any selection/edition/processing of each line read, then you could make it much simpler by reading each file in full and writing it in one go in the output file. You can do that with the function [`fileread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html).

Something like:

```
%% merge text data using "fileread"
steve = fopen('testout.txt','a');
for i =1:2
    StringFileContent = fileread( sprintf('test_%d.txt', i) ) ;
    fprintf(steve, StringFileContent );
end
fclose(steve) ;
```

Will produce exactly the same output than above and will be significantly faster for long and/or numerous files.
Just pay attention in this last code snippet, the file is **NOT** opened in text mode as before. Otherwise matlab will automatically insert `\r` before each `\n`, even if a `\r` was already present (in effect duplicating each `\r`). This is because the function `fileread` does not mess with the newlines, it simply read everything as a string.